# Undoing history.replaceState(...)

Tags: html, pushstate

If I have an app running at `http://example.com` I can use the following:

```
window.history.replaceState({}, null, '#5')
```

to update my address bar with `http://example.com/#5`.

Is it possible to undo this? Using JS, can I return the address bar to its original state?

Comment: Do you not wish to use `history.replaceState` again?

Comment: I can use it again, but `history.replaceState({}, null, '')` didn't do the trick.